# mysql: date_format converts the first week of 2016 into the last week

Tags: mysql, date-format

The first week of 2016, which is actually the 53rd week of 2015 is converted into 53rd week of 2016 by mysql.
How do I convert it to a real week, i.e. 53rd week of 2015?
http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2016

```
select date_format('2016-01-03 09:16:18','%y-%v');
16-53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select yearweek('2016-01-03',1);
```

The second parameter is the weekmode, value of 1 means weeks start on Monday.

Or

```
SELECT date_format( '2016-01-03 09:16:18', '%x-%v' )
```

The %x means week starts on Monday

Reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html